# tmux.conf is giving syntax error

Tags: terminal, tmux, fish

My `.tmux.conf` is

```
# https://github.com/seebi/tmux-colors-solarized/blob/master/tmuxcolors-256.conf
set-option -g status-style bg=colour235,fg=colour136,default # bg=base02, fg=yellow

# set window split
bind-key v split-window -h
bind-key b split-window

# default window title colors
set-window-option -g window-status-style fg=colour244,bg=default,dim # fg=base0

# active window title colors
set-window-option -g window-status-current-style fg=colour166,bg=default,bright # fg=orange

# pane border
set-option -g pane-border-style fg=colour235 #fg=base02
set-option -g pane-active-border-style fg=colour240 #fg=base01

# message text
set-option -g message-style bg=colour235,fg=colour166 # bg=base02, fg=orange

# pane number display
set-option -g display-panes-active-colour colour33 #blue
set-option -g display-panes-colour colour166 #orange
# clock
set-window-option -g clock-mode-colour green #green


set -g status-interval 1
set -g status-justify centre # center align window list
set -g status-left-length 20
set -g status-right-length 140
set -g status-left '#[fg=green]#H #[fg=black]• #[fg=green,bright]#(uname -r | cut -c 1-6)#[default]'
set -g status-right '#[fg=green,bg=default,bright]#(tmux-mem-cpu-load) #[fg=red,dim,bg=default]#(uptime | cut -f 4-5 -d " " | cut -f 1 -d ",") #[fg=white,bg=default]%a%l:%M:%S %p#[default] #[fg=blue]%Y-%m-%d'

# C-b is not acceptable -- Vim uses it
set-option -g prefix C-a
bind-key C-a last-window

# Start numbering at 1
set -g base-index 1

# Allows for faster key repetition
set -s escape-time 0

# Rather than constraining window size to the maximum size of any client 
# connected to the *session*, constrain window size to the maximum size of any 
# client connected to *that window*. Much more reasonable.
setw -g aggressive-resize on

# Allows us to use C-a a <command> to send commands to a TMUX session inside 
# another TMUX session
bind-key a send-prefix

# Activity monitoring
setw -g monitor-activity on
set -g visual-activity on

# hjkl pane traversal
bind h select-pane -L
bind j select-pane -D
bind k select-pane -U
bind l select-pane -R

# set to main-horizontal, 66% height for main pane
bind m run-shell "~/.tmux/scripts/resize-adaptable.sh -l main-horizontal -p 66"
# Same thing for verical layouts
bind M run-shell "~/.tmux/scripts/resize-adaptable.sh -l main-vertical -p 50"

bind-key C command-prompt -p "Name of new window: " "new-window -n '%%'"

# reload config
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display-message "Config reloaded..."

# auto window rename
set-window-option -g automatic-rename
set-option -g allow-rename

# https://github.com/edkolev/dots/blob/master/tmux.conf
# Updates for tmux 1.9's current pane splitting paths.

# from powerline
run-shell "tmux set-environment -g TMUX_VERSION_MAJOR $(tmux -V | cut -d' ' -f2 | cut -d'.' -f1 | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')"
run-shell "tmux set-environment -g TMUX_VERSION_MINOR $(tmux -V | cut -d' ' -f2 | cut -d'.' -f2 | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')"

# Vi copypaste mode
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
if-shell "test '\( #{$TMUX_VERSION_MAJOR} -eq 2 -a #{$TMUX_VERSION_MINOR} -ge 4 \)'" 'bind-key -Tcopy-mode-vi v send -X begin-selection; bind-key -Tcopy-mode-vi y send -X copy-selection-and-cancel'
if-shell '\( #{$TMUX_VERSION_MAJOR} -eq 2 -a #{$TMUX_VERSION_MINOR} -lt 4\) -o #{$TMUX_VERSION_MAJOR} -le 1' 'bind-key -t vi-copy v begin-selection; bind-key -t vi-copy y copy-selection'

# status bar
if-shell '\( #{$TMUX_VERSION_MAJOR} -eq 2 -a #{$TMUX_VERSION_MINOR} -lt 2\) -o #{$TMUX_VERSION_MAJOR} -le 1' 'set-option -g status-utf8 on'

# rm mouse mode fail
if-shell '\( #{$TMUX_VERSION_MAJOR} -eq 2 -a #{$TMUX_VERSION_MINOR} -ge 1\)' 'set -g mouse off'
if-shell '\( #{$TMUX_VERSION_MAJOR} -eq 2 -a #{$TMUX_VERSION_MINOR} -lt 1\) -o #{$TMUX_VERSION_MAJOR} -le 1' 'set -g mode-mouse off'

# fix pane_current_path on new window and splits
if-shell "test '#{$TMUX_VERSION_MAJOR} -gt 1 -o \( #{$TMUX_VERSION_MAJOR} -eq 1 -a #{$TMUX_VERSION_MINOR} -ge 8 \)'" 'unbind c; bind c new-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"'
if-shell "test '#{$TMUX_VERSION_MAJOR} -gt 1 -o \( #{$TMUX_VERSION_MAJOR} -eq 1 -a #{$TMUX_VERSION_MINOR} -ge 8 \)'" "unbind '\"'; bind '\"' split-window -v -c '#{pane_current_path}'"
if-shell "test '#{$TMUX_VERSION_MAJOR} -gt 1 -o \( #{$TMUX_VERSION_MAJOR} -eq 1 -a #{$TMUX_VERSION_MINOR} -ge 8 \)'" 'unbind v; bind v split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}"'
if-shell "test '#{$TMUX_VERSION_MAJOR} -gt 1 -o \( #{$TMUX_VERSION_MAJOR} -eq 1 -a #{$TMUX_VERSION_MINOR} -ge 8 \)'" 'unbind %; bind % split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}"'


# Colors
# How to use true colors in vim under tmux? #1246 for 2.6 and higher
# https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/1246:
# set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"
# set -ga terminal-overrides ",*256col*:Tc"
# 2.5 and lower:
# set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"

# Doesn't work on iterm2 / mac
# if-shell "test '\( #{$TMUX_VERSION_MAJOR} -eq 2 -a #{$TMUX_VERSION_MINOR} -ge 6 \)'" 'set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"'
# if-shell "test '\( #{$TMUX_VERSION_MAJOR} -eq 2 -a #{$TMUX_VERSION_MINOR} -ge 6 \)'" 'set -ga terminal-overrides ",*256col*:Tc"'

# Try screen256-color (https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/622):
if-shell "test '\( #{$TMUX_VERSION_MAJOR} -eq 2 -a #{$TMUX_VERSION_MINOR} -ge 6 \)'" 'set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"'
if-shell "test '\( #{$TMUX_VERSION_MAJOR} -eq 2 -a #{$TMUX_VERSION_MINOR} -ge 6 \)'" 'set -ga terminal-overrides ",screen-256color:Tc"'

if-shell '\( #{$TMUX_VERSION_MAJOR} -eq 2 -a #{$TMUX_VERSION_MINOR} -lt 6\) -o #{$TMUX_VERSION_MAJOR} -le 1' 'set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"'

set-option -g default-command fish
set -g mouse
set -g set-clipboard external
bind -T root MouseUp2Pane paste
```

When I do `source ~/.tmux.conf`, I get:

```
bash: set-option: command not found
bash: bind-key: command not found
bash: bind-key: command not found
bash: set-window-option: command not found
bash: set-window-option: command not found
bash: set-option: command not found
bash: set-option: command not found
bash: set-option: command not found
bash: set-option: command not found
bash: set-option: command not found
bash: set-window-option: command not found
bash: set: -g: invalid option
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
bash: set: -g: invalid option
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
bash: set: -g: invalid option
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
bash: set: -g: invalid option
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
bash: set: -g: invalid option
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
bash: set: -g: invalid option
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
bash: set-option: command not found
bash: bind-key: command not found
bash: set: -g: invalid option
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
bash: set: -s: invalid option
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
bash: setw: command not found
bash: bind-key: command not found
bash: setw: command not found
bash: set: -g: invalid option
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
readline: h: no key sequence terminator
readline: select-pane: no key sequence terminator
readline: -L: no key sequence terminator
readline: j: no key sequence terminator
readline: select-pane: no key sequence terminator
readline: -D: no key sequence terminator
readline: k: no key sequence terminator
readline: select-pane: no key sequence terminator
readline: -U: no key sequence terminator
readline: l: no key sequence terminator
readline: select-pane: no key sequence terminator
readline: -R: no key sequence terminator
readline: m: no key sequence terminator
readline: run-shell: no key sequence terminator
readline: ~/.tmux/scripts/resize-adaptable.sh: unknown key modifier
readline: M: no key sequence terminator
readline: run-shell: no key sequence terminator
readline: ~/.tmux/scripts/resize-adaptable.sh: unknown key modifier
bash: bind-key: command not found
readline: r: no key sequence terminator
readline: source-file: no key sequence terminator
readline: /home/sintan/.tmux.conf: no key sequence terminator
readline: ;: no key sequence terminator
readline: display-message: no key sequence terminator
bash: set-window-option: command not found
bash: set-option: command not found
bash: run-shell: command not found
bash: run-shell: command not found
bash: set-window-option: command not found
bash: if-shell: command not found
bash: if-shell: command not found
bash: if-shell: command not found
bash: if-shell: command not found
bash: if-shell: command not found
bash: if-shell: command not found
bash: if-shell: command not found
bash: if-shell: command not found
bash: if-shell: command not found
bash: if-shell: command not found
bash: if-shell: command not found
bash: if-shell: command not found
bash: set-option: command not found
bash: set: -g: invalid option
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
bash: set: -g: invalid option
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
bash: bind: -T: invalid option
bind: usage: bind [-lpsvPSVX] [-m keymap] [-f filename] [-q name] [-u name] [-r keyseq] [-x keyseq:shell-command] [keyseq:readline-function or readline-command]
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

With `source ~/.tmux.conf` you are using your shell (bash in your case) built-in command to execute your conf file.

when you want to tell tmux to reread its config you need to press Ctrl + b , release both keys then type `:` Then you will get a prompt a the bottom of your tmux window where you can type `source ~/.tmux.conf` . Now it's tmux receiving the command, not bash.

Comment: It still gives syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

About syntax error.
In line 105 edit text to:

```
if-shell "test '#{$TMUX_VERSION_MAJOR} -gt 1 -o \( #{$TMUX_VERSION_MAJOR} -eq 1 -a #{$TMUX_VERSION_MINOR} -ge 8 \)'" "unbind '\%'; bind '\%' split-window -h -c '#{pane_current_path}'"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Do you type `source ~/.tmux.conf` to the shell? In that case, you should try `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf`, because .tmux.conf is a tmux configuration file that contains commands that are executable only for tmux, that is why you need the `tmux` word in the beginning.

Comment: Hello, please add some more details as to why this is the recommended solution.

Comment: @Destroy666 
Details added